# Error: Failed to fetch the Solidity compiler

Tags: node.js, solidity, truffle

I am new to Truffle and going through the Metacoin tutorial; I followed all the steps but when I do truffle compile, I get the following:

```
Error: Failed to fetch the Solidity compiler from the following locations: https://relay.trufflesuite.com/solc/bin/,https://solc-bin.ethereum.org/bin/,https://ethereum.github.io/solc-bin/bin/. Are you connected to the internet?
```

I am connected to Internet and using:
Truffle v5.5.26 (core: 5.5.26)
Ganache v7.4.0
Solidity - 0.8.13 (solc-js)
Node v16.13.1
Web3.js v1.7.4

Comment: Please Provide Minimum Reproducible code..

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the solidity compiler globally on your computer.

```
npm install -g solc
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never run `sudo` as suggested by the above answer. Although it will work, it exposes your PC to attack since you give admin privileges to these packages.

Instead, you should run `npm doctor` to check your node environment health. This should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

that is most likely npm issue, npm cannot fetch the packages. You were either not connected to the internet or run this command:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

or

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue. was able to get it to work by running `sudo truffle compile`

You'd have to have sudo-er access though for this to work.